# Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error Group clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, firebase, ibm-mobilefirst, cordova-plugins, mach-o

I tried this in **Xcode Version 8.3.2 (8E2002)**.
Trying in **IBM mobile first(7.1**) to integrate **Cordova FCM Plugin**.(https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/).
Its success in android.

When I included FCM sdk (.framework) file using General->Linked Framework and libraries. This issue is coming.
**(I tried pod libraries instead of these SDK. Same error happens)**

> I tried BITCODE to NO. tried POD libraries , I got the same issue
>   again. Tried Clean and Build. Removed Derived data from xcode
>   preference. I checked Duplicate files.(No duplicates). I had given
>   -ObjC in other linker flags.

**Framework search path**

> $(inherited)
>       $(SRCROOT) 
>      "$(SRCROOT)/Frameworks" 
>       $(PROJECT_DIR)/Firebase/Analytics 
>       $(PROJECT_DIR)/Firebase/Crash 
>       $(PROJECT_DIR)/Firebase/Messaging
>       $(PROJECT_DIR)/Firebase/RemoteConfig
>       $(PROJECT_DIR)/Frameworks

**Library Search path**

> $(inherited)
>   $(SRCROOT)
>   $(PROJECT_DIR)/Classes/HotlineSDK

## Other linker flags

**Debug** :

> -ObjC

**Distribution:**

> -force_load 
>   "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/libCordova.a"
>   -ObjC

**Release**

> -force_load 
>   "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/libCordova.a"
>   -ObjC

If I remove these FCM sdk frameworks . Link error will disappear.

Please help me to clear this.

**Build Log**

> Showing All Issues
>
> Build target CordovaLib of project CordovaLib with configuration Debug
>
> Build target myIphone of project myIphone
>   with configuration Debug
>
> warning: User supplied UIDeviceFamily key in the Info.plist will be
>   overwritten. Please use the build setting TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY and
>   remove UIDeviceFamily from your Info.plist.
>
> CompileC
>   /Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Debug-iphoneos/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/HotlinePlugin.o
>   Classes/HotlinePlugin.m normal armv7 objective-c
>   com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>       cd "/Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native"
>       export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -x objective-c -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=c99 -fobjc-arc -gmodules -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-bool-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.3.sdk
>   -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -g -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -Wno-infinite-recursion -iquote /Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Debug-iphoneos/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/LuLuOne-generated-files.hmap
>   -I/Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Debug-iphoneos/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/LuLuOne-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Debug-iphoneos/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/LuLuOne-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Debug-iphoneos/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/LuLuOne-project-headers.hmap
>   -I/Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include
>   -I/Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work\ Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native/CordovaLib/build/Debug-iphoneos/include
>   -I/Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/usr/local/lib/include
>   -I/Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/UninstalledProducts/include
>   -I/Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
>   -I/Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/include
>   -I/Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Debug-iphoneos/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/DerivedSources/armv7
>   -I/Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Debug-iphoneos/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/DerivedSources
>   -F/Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
>   -F/Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work\ Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native
>   -F/Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work\ Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native/Frameworks
>   -F/Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work\ Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native/Firebase/Analytics
>   -F/Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work\ Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native/Firebase/Crash
>   -F/Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work\ Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native/Firebase/Messaging
>   -F/Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work\ Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native/Firebase/RemoteConfig
>   -DDEBUG -include /Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/luluforexLuluoneIphone_Prefix-efjdqfhfrwriwydvgpcaroblwpch/luluforexLuluoneIphone_Prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Debug-iphoneos/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/HotlinePlugin.d
>   --serialize-diagnostics /Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Debug-iphoneos/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/HotlinePlugin.dia
>   -c /Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work\ Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native/Classes/HotlinePlugin.m
>   -o /Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Debug-iphoneos/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/HotlinePlugin.o
>
> /Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work
>   Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native/Classes/HotlinePlugin.m:15:17:
>   warning: method definition for 'registerPushNotification:' not found
>   [-Wincomplete-implementation] @implementation HotlinePlugin:CDVPlugin
>                   ^ In file included from /Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work
>   Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native/Classes/HotlinePlugin.m:10:
>   /Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work
>   Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native/Classes/HotlinePlugin.h:16:1:
>   note: method 'registerPushNotification:' declared here
>   -(void)registerPushNotification:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command; ^ 1 warning generated.
>
> CompileC
>   /Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Debug-iphoneos/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/HotlinePlugin.o
>   Classes/HotlinePlugin.m normal armv7s objective-c
>   com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>       cd "/Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native"
>       export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -x objective-c -arch armv7s -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=c99 -fobjc-arc -gmodules -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-bool-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.3.sdk
>   -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -g -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -Wno-infinite-recursion -iquote /Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Debug-iphoneos/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/LuLuOne-generated-files.hmap
>   -I/Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Debug-iphoneos/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/LuLuOne-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Debug-iphoneos/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/LuLuOne-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Debug-iphoneos/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/LuLuOne-project-headers.hmap
>   -I/Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include
>   -I/Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work\ Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native/CordovaLib/build/Debug-iphoneos/include
>   -I/Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/usr/local/lib/include
>   -I/Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/UninstalledProducts/include
>   -I/Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
>   -I/Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/include
>   -I/Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Debug-iphoneos/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/DerivedSources/armv7s
>   -I/Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Debug-iphoneos/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/DerivedSources
>   -F/Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
>   -F/Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work\ Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native
>   -F/Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work\ Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native/Frameworks
>   -F/Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work\ Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native/Firebase/Analytics
>   -F/Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work\ Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native/Firebase/Crash
>   -F/Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work\ Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native/Firebase/Messaging
>   -F/Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work\ Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native/Firebase/RemoteConfig
>   -DDEBUG -include /Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/luluforexLuluoneIphone_Prefix-dyliholualcvxycaywvucajqygrc/luluforexLuluoneIphone_Prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Debug-iphoneos/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/HotlinePlugin.d
>   --serialize-diagnostics /Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Debug-iphoneos/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/HotlinePlugin.dia
>   -c /Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work\ Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native/Classes/HotlinePlugin.m
>   -o /Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Debug-iphoneos/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/HotlinePlugin.o
>
> /Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work
>   Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native/Classes/HotlinePlugin.m:15:17:
>   warning: method definition for 'registerPushNotification:' not found
>   [-Wincomplete-implementation] @implementation HotlinePlugin:CDVPlugin
>                   ^ In file included from /Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work
>   Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native/Classes/HotlinePlugin.m:10:
>   /Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work
>   Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native/Classes/HotlinePlugin.h:16:1:
>   note: method 'registerPushNotification:' declared here
>   -(void)registerPushNotification:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command; ^ 1 warning generated.
>
> CompileC
>   /Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Debug-iphoneos/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/HotlinePlugin.o
>   Classes/HotlinePlugin.m normal arm64 objective-c
>   com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>       cd "/Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native"
>       export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -x objective-c -arch arm64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=c99 -fobjc-arc -gmodules -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-bool-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.3.sdk
>   -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -g -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -Wno-infinite-recursion -iquote /Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Debug-iphoneos/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/LuLuOne-generated-files.hmap
>   -I/Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Debug-iphoneos/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/LuLuOne-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Debug-iphoneos/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/LuLuOne-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Debug-iphoneos/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/LuLuOne-project-headers.hmap
>   -I/Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include
>   -I/Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work\ Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native/CordovaLib/build/Debug-iphoneos/include
>   -I/Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/usr/local/lib/include
>   -I/Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/UninstalledProducts/include
>   -I/Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
>   -I/Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/include
>   -I/Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Debug-iphoneos/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/DerivedSources/arm64
>   -I/Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Debug-iphoneos/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/DerivedSources
>   -F/Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
>   -F/Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work\ Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native
>   -F/Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work\ Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native/Frameworks
>   -F/Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work\ Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native/Firebase/Analytics
>   -F/Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work\ Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native/Firebase/Crash
>   -F/Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work\ Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native/Firebase/Messaging
>   -F/Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work\ Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native/Firebase/RemoteConfig
>   -DDEBUG -include /Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/luluforexLuluoneIphone_Prefix-cbrpxglmvouqlzdqvhoxutszcgmk/luluforexLuluoneIphone_Prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Debug-iphoneos/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/HotlinePlugin.d
>   --serialize-diagnostics /Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Debug-iphoneos/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/HotlinePlugin.dia
>   -c /Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work\ Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native/Classes/HotlinePlugin.m
>   -o /Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Debug-iphoneos/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/HotlinePlugin.o
>
> /Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work
>   Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native/Classes/HotlinePlugin.m:118:46:
>   warning: values of type 'NSInteger' should not be used as format
>   arguments; add an explicit cast to 'long' instead [-Wformat]
>       NSLog(@" The unread count value is: %d", unreadCount);
>                                           ~~   ^~~~~~~~~~~
>                                           %ld  (long) /Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work
>   Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native/Classes/HotlinePlugin.m:15:17:
>   warning: method definition for 'registerPushNotification:' not found
>   [-Wincomplete-implementation] @implementation HotlinePlugin:CDVPlugin
>                   ^ In file included from /Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work
>   Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native/Classes/HotlinePlugin.m:10:
>   /Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work
>   Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native/Classes/HotlinePlugin.h:16:1:
>   note: method 'registerPushNotification:' declared here
>   -(void)registerPushNotification:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command; ^ 2 warnings generated.
>
> Ld
>   /Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Debug-iphoneos/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/LuLuOne
>   normal armv7s
>       cd "/Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native"
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch armv7s -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.3.sdk
>   -L/Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
>   -L/Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work\ Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native
>   -L/Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work\ Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native/Classes/HotlineSDK
>   -F/Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
>   -F/Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work\ Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native
>   -F/Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work\ Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native/Frameworks
>   -F/Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work\ Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native/Firebase/Analytics
>   -F/Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work\ Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native/Firebase/Crash
>   -F/Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work\ Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native/Firebase/Messaging
>   -F/Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work\ Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native/Firebase/RemoteConfig
>   -filelist /Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Debug-iphoneos/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/LuLuOne.LinkFileList
>   -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Debug-iphoneos/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/LuLuOne_lto.o
>   -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -framework IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationHybrid -framework FirebaseRemoteConfig -framework FirebaseMessaging -framework
>   FirebaseCrash -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework FirebaseCore
>   -framework FirebaseInstanceID -framework GoogleToolboxForMac -lc++ -lstdc++.6 -framework CoreTelephony -framework ImageIO -framework sqlcipher
>   /Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCordova.a
>   -framework Security -framework CoreMedia -lz -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework AddressBook -framework AddressBookUI -framework AudioToolbox -lFDHotlineSDK -framework AssetsLibrary -framework AVFoundation -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreLocation -framework MediaPlayer -framework QuartzCore -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CoreMotion -framework MobileCoreServices -framework CoreData -Xlinker -dependency_info
>   -Xlinker /Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Debug-iphoneos/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/LuLuOne_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/it-devops-roney/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/luluforexLuluoneIphone-exmdpkdrgewycqgnuvmbntthipqx/Build/Intermediates/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Debug-iphoneos/luluforexLuluoneIphone.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/LuLuOne
>
> ld: file is universal (4 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s
>   slice: /Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work
>   Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native/Firebase/Analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics
>   file '/Users/it-devops-roney/Documents/Roney/Work
>   Tools/Trial2/lulumoneyapp-web/package/luluone/apps/luluone/iphone/native/Firebase/Analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics'
>   for architecture armv7s clang: error: linker command failed with exit
>   code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> Build failed    06/06/17, 12:35 PM

Comment: you have set other linker flag to "$(inherited)"

Comment: I given $(inherited) in Other linker flags. Then its changed to -ObjC automatically for Debug.. linker error still there

Comment: @RoneyFrancis Can you paste your app build log here ??

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to build an app with `armv7s` as one of the architecture. As this architecture slice is not packaged in  `FirebaseAnalytics.framework`, it will cause build failure.

Kindly remove `armv7s` from the valid architectures which you can find inside `Build Architectures` tab & re-build your app. This will resolve the issue.

Comment: Is there any dependency there? 
I'm using IBM JSONstore to keep data , its using this architecture. 
If i remove this.. may cause any other issue? can i replace this with any other?

Comment: Issue is not solved. I got another issue like
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GPBDescriptor", referenced from: and so on.
and it leads ti linked error

Comment: @RoneyFrancis This issue needs to be investigated further. Please open a PMR with IBM.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys... I expect a solution from you...
I will open PMR

Comment: Getting same issue , did you find solution for this issue